# Beta / Pilot program for Lightning for the Desktop?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, isv, ui, pilot

Is there any official or unofficial pilot program for Lightning for Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Please contact your SFDC AE, SE, TSE, etc. and ask them about the program.